# CakePHP get records with date in future

Tags: mysql, date, cakephp

I have a table of events that have a "Date" column.
I am trying to retrieve all the events that are in the future, but I am having trouble building the find function correctly.

I have attempted to use the conditions parameter as follows:

```
$options = array('conditions' => array("Event.Date >= CONVERT(date, SYSDATETIME()"));
$events = $this->Event->find('all', $options);
```

But this causes a redirect loop.
How would be the correct way to achieve this?
TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$options = array(
    'conditions' => array(
        "Event.Date >=" => date('Y-m-d', strtotime("now"))
    )
);
```

You don't actually need the strtotime("now") argument, but I find that it aids readability and maintainability when you come back to this snippet later on.